# How to Redirect to another page when token-session null in struts2.0?

Tags: struts2

I had used token-session interceptor for duplicate form submission.Its working fine for me.But i have to redirect to another action when invalid token generated.

i tried

register
            
            
            Registration!input
            myhome

Its giving me **Form token GRCVNXBATIHD2SXL5VY62SY3YAWQX15J does not match the session token null.** but not reirecting

Comment: Please supply the code that you are currently using to try to redirect on an invalid token.

Answer (score 0):

The intercept method in the struts2 intercepter returns a String that maps to a reseult.  If "invocation.invoke();" is returned then the interceptor continues the execution stack.  If another string is returned, then a different result occurs.
So, you need something like this in your intercept method,

```
if(isTokenValid)
{
   return invocation.invoke();
}else
{
   return "inValidToken";
}
```

Also, [define a result](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/result-types.html) for "inValidToken".  A redirect action might fit your need.  You also might want to use a global result.

Show some code, or give me some information and I can clarify some more :).